# Too many security updates for Microsoft.NET Framework 4

Tags: security, .net-framework

As you can see by the picture I've included, I have several of the same .NET Framework's installed, and I don't know what to do about it. I know it's an important program, so I don't want to screw anything up, but this can't be right. There's currently 18 "Security Updates for Microsoft Framework 4...", and 7 more "Updates for Microsoft Framework 4...". All of these were created on the same day (3/18/10) and they are all 118.01 MB (except 3)

Can I get rid of them all, and reinstall the .NET Frameworks that I need?

[image: My uninstaller Program]

Comment: Heh, that truly is about the right number. .NET is updated just about every month. The dupes are a Microsoft initial release that didn't quite do the job and had to be re-released hence the V2 prominently displayed. And you don't uninstall .NET unless you like Stygian Darkness and suffering the pain of all the circles of Dante's Hell, often followed by a drive wipe and reinstall of the OS. Been there, done that with a 1.1 .NET installation damaged by a really bad Microsoft update. You really don't want to go there.

Answer (score 2):

each update should have a KB number, which you can search for online, to find the details on the patch.

I notice that when I go to Installed Updates, I see Installed date, but not Created Date. if you installed the .net Framework 4 on 3/18/10, they were likely installed that same day.

My recommendation is to Leave them in place unless you are having a problem with a program that runs on the .Net 4 framework.

If you are really concerned about it, uninstall the .Net framework of your choice, and reinstall it. windows update will download the patches it believes you should have.